# How to create extra relation in pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have following tables,

- users -> id
- diplomas -> id
- diploma_user -> id, user_id, diploma_id, invoice_id
- invoices -> id

I can get the diplomas of users by defining this relation in User class.

```
public function diplomas(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Diploma::class);
}
```

How I can get diplomas of users with the invoices? **$user->diploma->pivot->invoice**?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define an extra pivot model that holds the relation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models

```
public function diplomas(){
   return $this
        ->belongsToMany(Diploma::class)
        ->using(DiplomaUser::class)
        ->withPivot('invoice_id');
}
```

and your DiplomaUserClass:

```
class DiplomaUser extends Pivot
{
    public function invoice() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Invoice::class)
    }
}
```

Now you can do `$user->diplomas->first()->pivot->invoice`

Comment: But it is not loading invoice relationship and even invoice_id field on the pivot table. i'm only seeing, user_id and diploma_id on the pivot.

Comment: try adding the ->withPivot('invoice_id'); configuration: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Comment: That's worked now, how I can eager load the invoice on the pivot table? So I can return pivot with invoice detail in the json response?